# Substring performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

This give the exact result:

```
SUBSTRING(em.message, CHARINDEX('"',em.message)+1,LEN(em.message)-CHARINDEX('"',REVERSE(em.message))-CHARINDEX('"',em.message))
```

But is there a faster way for the DB to do this in SQL Server 2016?

Comment: Not really. Database engines aren't really built for this kind of work. They assume you either store this data in it's own column or will clean the column in client code.

Comment: you could maybe write a CLR function but I doubt it would be quicker than the default functionality

Comment: It's how the SSISDB stores the data :|

Comment: Can you show some sample data and expected output? There may be a slightly faster way, but it's unlikely to be fast. Maybe you are using functions that aren't needed...

Comment: My dudes, this is the `SSISDB` which contains the logging `catalog.event_messages` for SSIS packages. So the comments implying bad database design are kind of hilarious. OP, I am assuming you're trying to parse things like server names or file locations from the event messages, you can try joining to `event_messages_context` but I fear it won't be any faster or easier since you would need to filter the noise. And you would still need to get the context id/property name and value anyway... kind of like searching for a needle in a haystack vs forging a new needle...

Comment: Maybe a custom logging level might cut down on the number of records you are querying in the catalog? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/performance/integration-services-ssis-logging I don't think you can customize the message text though, unfortunately.